# trouble echoing a sql query in the order i want

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, echo

im new in php sql and stuff, and I've been trying to think in a way to show in order a SELECT.

Let me explain this better, this is the query I have:

```
$resultAraucania = mysql_query("SELECT nombre.idNombre, 
                                       nombre.nombre AS nombreNombre, 
                                       comuna.nombre AS nombreComuna, 
                                       giro.nombre AS nombreGiro, 
                                       provincia.nombre AS nombreProvincia, 
                                       region.nombre AS nombreRegion 
                                  FROM nombre 
                            INNER JOIN comuna ON nombre.Comuna_idComuna = comuna.idComuna 
                            INNER JOIN giro ON nombre.Giro_idGiro = giro.idGiro 
                            INNER JOIN provincia ON comuna.Provincia_idProvincia = provincia.idProvincia 
                            INNER JOIN region ON provincia.Region_idRegion = region.idRegion 
                                 WHERE provincia.Region_idRegion = 9
                              ORDER BY nombreProvincia, nombreComuna, nombreGiro, nombreNombre");
```

See at the end, I ordered by nombreProvincia, nombreComuna, nombreGiro, nombreNombre.
How can I echo it in a way that I get first all the results for nombreProvincia, inside all the result for nombreComuna, and so on so I get something like this:

**nombreProvincia1**

```
nombreComuna1
  nombreGiro1
     nombreNombre1, nombreNombre2, nombreNombre3...

  nombreGiro2
     nombreNombre4, nombreNombre5, nombreNombre6...

  nombreGiron...
    nombreNombren...

nombreComunan..
```

**nombreProvincia2**

```
nombreComuna21...
  nombreGiro...
    nombreNombre....
```

Hope I explain this well enough, I thought doing something like this:

```
<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
    echo $row['nombreProvicia']."<br/>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
      echo "&nbsp;".$row['nombreComuna']."<br/>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
        echo "&nbsp;".$row['nombreGiro']."<br/>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
          echo "&nbsp;".$row['nombreNombre']."<br/>";
        }
      }
    }
  } ?>
```

but it didn't work, hope somebody can help me in this. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like that. It's not optimal, but you should understand how it works.

```
$nombreProvincia = "";
$nombreComuna = "";
$nombreGiro = "";
$nombreNombre = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
    if ($nombreProvincia == $row['nombreProvincia']) {
        if ($nombreComuna == $row['nombreComuna']) {
            if ($nombreGiro == $row['nombreGiro']) {
                $nombreNombre[] = $row['nombreNombre'];
            }
            else { //nombreGiro
                echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . implode(', ', $nombreNombre);
                $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
                echo '<br/>&nbsp;'.$nombreGiro;
                $nombreNombre = array($row['nombreNombre']);
            }
        }
        else { // nombreComuna
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . implode(', ', $nombreNombre);
            $nombreComuna = $row['nombreComuna'];
            echo '<br/>'.nombreComuna;
            $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
            echo '<br/>&nbsp;'.$nombreGiro;
            $nombreNombre = array($row['nombreNombre']);
        }
    }
    else { // nombreProvincia
        if (!empty($nombreNombre)) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . implode(', ', $nombreNombre);
        }
        $nombreProvincia = $row['nombreProvincia'];
        echo '<h1>'.$nombreProvincia.'</h1>'."\n";
        $nombreComuna = $row['nombreComuna'];
        echo '<br/>'.nombreComuna;
        $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
        echo '<br/>&nbsp;'.$nombreGiro;
        $nombreNombre = array($row['nombreNombre']);
    }
}
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . implode(', ', $nombreNombre);
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much!, it works perfectly!, also i thought in doing a query with group by, do you think that you make everything easier??

Comment: No. GROUP BY is when you want to do some aggregation functions on queries, like SUM or MAX...